# How to create a stacked bar chart with a series in matplotlib or seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-visualization

It sounds simple but I cant get a stacked bar chart.  I got a series after grouping by a column in a dataframe.

```
s1 = df_sort.groupby('loan_status')['count_loans'].sum()
s1

loan_status
Fully paid        8045
Not fully paid    1533
Name: count_loans, dtype: int64
```

I have tried

```
s1.T.plot.bar(stacked=True)

s1.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True)
```

which produces two individual bars?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the groupby line to:

```
df = df.groupby(by = 'loan_status').sum().T
```

Then you can plot with:

```
df.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I think you change the final values of the OP?

Comment: Yes because I randomly generated an other dataframe from which group-by, so values are different from the ones reported in the question

Comment: thanks! do you know how to remove 'count_loans'?

Comment: You should assign `df.plot` as `ax = df.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)` and then you can remove the tick label with `ax.set_xticklabels('')`

Comment: ok :) thank you. I am now trying to put the percentage values on it - maybe you know how to do it as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69306442/stacked-bar-showing-percentage-values-for-2-variables-in-matplotlib/69306610#69306610

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your `Series` to a `DataFrame` else you can't transpose:

```
s1.to_frame().T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: stackbar]