# Stacked bar showing percentage values for 2 variables in Matplotlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot, bar-chart

I saw a code for a stacked percentage bar plot in another post, however, am having trouble adopting it for my plot.
[Display totals and percentage in stacked bar chart using DataFrame.plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51495982/display-totals-and-percentage-in-stacked-bar-chart-using-dataframe-plot)

```
data = {'Paid':[8045],'Not Paid':[1533]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = [''])
df['Total'] = df['Paid']+df['Not Paid']

df_rel = (df[df.columns[0:2]].div(df.iloc[0, 2])*100).round(2)
df_rel
```

So I want to build a stacked bar showing the percentage values for each of my two variables on it:

```
df_rel.plot( kind='bar',stacked = True,mark_right = True) # this is ok

for n in df_rel:
    for i, (a,b,c) in enumerate(zip(df_rel.iloc[:,:][n], df[n], df_rel[n])):
         plt.text(a -b / 2, i, str(c) + '%', va = 'center', ha = 'center')  # this gives an error.
```

Can somebody help me figure out whats wrong?  I'm getting 'ValueError: Image size of 1318810x237 pixels is too large.'

Also this approach seems complicated maybe someone knows a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for the inner loop, just calculate the cummulated bar height and add text there:

[Full example](https://akuiper.com/console/SHDHhyWlBjIt)

```
df_rel.plot( kind='bar',stacked = True,mark_right = True) # this is ok
h = 0
for col in df_rel:
    h += (p := df_rel[col].iat[0])      # calculate current bar height
    plt.text(0, h - p / 2, f'{p}%', va='center', ha='center')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It says invalid syntax?  I have python 3.6.13 thats why its not recognising  the ' :=' operator. do you know another way to do it?

Comment: `:=` does nothing but assign values in line. If you are using older versions of python, you can separate it into two lines: `p = df_rel[col].iat[0]; h += p`